# How Can I load a specific DIV from an external webpage, into a specific DIV of my website?

Tags: load, external, html

I Want to load a Specific Div of an external webpage into a specific Div (No iframe) Of my own website. 
for example:
I have a div like this in my own website:

```
<div id="weather-status"> Weather Status </div>
```

I have this site too: http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/
and I want to load a table from this site (http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/) into my div (Weather Status)
How Can I Do This?

Comment: table `id` might be anything like this: `weather` @Arif

Comment: @Arif: table id is not very important

Comment: but you need the table data only..right?

Comment: @Arif: No, I need `table` data & Design. Exactly a position of a webpage that starts with specific `table` or `div`. So `div` might be instead of the `table` and The `div` or `table` element might have `id` or not.

Comment: answer is edited now. please accept the answer if it is workable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
   $url = "http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/";
   $page_all = file_get_contents($url); 

   preg_match('#<table class="border2 lpad wa">(.*)</table>#ms', $page_all, $div_array);


   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($div_array[0]);
   echo "</pre>";
?>
```

With the following CSS :

```
.wa {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.border2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D7D6DC;
}

.lpad tr td {
    padding: 0.2em;
}
```

Comment: @Meghdad Hadidi which version of php do you use?

Comment: I'm using php 5.3.8 and it is running well

Comment: `PHP Version 5.1.4`    

I will test this code on an online host now.

Comment: Cool! Worked very nice my friend, but before the table, it prints following code:
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => `

Comment: your previous solution worked well, but i want to do that for another website, so how can I write a true pattern for `preg_match` to extract what I want?

Comment: For example: www.something.com/show.php?n=2564 and I want to extract a div with `class='someclass'`, how can I do this