# Hyperlink to a certain "id"-attribute on an external webpage (automatically have the content with that "id" clicked on)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A question about loading specific "`id`"-attributed (external) content onto your own (internal) page, e.g. a `div`, has already been answered, here: [How Can I load a specific DIV from an external webpage, into a specific DIV of my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163412/how-can-i-load-a-specific-div-from-an-external-webpage-into-a-specific-div-of-m).

However, is it possible, not to incorporate external "`id`"-attributed content internally, like in the referred question (and many other similar ones), **but to have an internal hyperlink, which (when clicked on), not only links to the `base-URL` where the external (e.g.) `<div id="`...`">` is located, but also automatically leads to a mouse-click on to that element (e.g.) `div` with a certain `id`.**

Is it possible that this post: [How to load a certain div of an external webpage on another webpage that is on a different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394791/how-to-load-a-certain-div-of-an-external-webpage-on-another-webpage-that-is-on-a) has some jQuery mod/library for it? For the moment, I am not familiar enough to understand well how to implement it for an automatic mouse-click-application.

- I guess this post is an almost-duplicate of: [How do I select and open a random link of a certain class on an external webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030770/how-do-i-select-and-open-a-random-link-of-a-certain-class-on-an-external-webpage), however it talks about opening content with a `class`-attribute, not a unique `id`-attribute.

Do you think it is possible using the `this.doSomething=function(){` JS function, and is this the best way to go?

Many thanks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, this question is far too broad. Secondly, once you've made the request to retrieve the HTML of the website (assuming it event works via JS if it's a third party site) you can hack it around as you like - it's just a string that's returned.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - *Thanks.* Perhaps the question seems broad since I am generally under-experienced, and my different suggestions seem to be diverting and wild guesses? In my specific case, the `id`-attributed content is an `img`. In general,  what I am referring to, is an `id`, which is easily findable on the `base-URL` and can be called at, like so: `base-URL` **#id**. --- *Any help with the possible use of JS would be greatly appreciated.*